# How to pass parameters from controller to service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My goal is to create an http post method in the service that gets the following parameters from the controller:
id, firstname,lastname,email,phonenumber
,in the controller:

```
function updateClient(client){
    var clientId=client.id;
    var firstName=$("#clientFirstName");
    var lastName=$("#clientLastName");
    var email=$("#clientEmail");
    var phoneNumber=$("#clientPhoneNumber");
    updateClient.postClient().then(function(data) {

    });
}
```

and in the service:

```
  testProjectApp.factory('updateClient', function($http, $q) {
   return { ...
```

Comment: You need to add the service to the list of dependencies in the controller, and then pass the parameters by calling to the function in that service

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the function in the object you are returning:

```
testProjectApp.factory('updateClient', function($http, $q) {
   return { 
       postClient : function(firstName, lastName) {
           //do stuff
       }
   }
});
```